# Android fragment can't read bundle. Bundle is always NULL

Tags: android, android-fragments, null, bundle

I wrote a custom static method to create my fragment. Fragment is a subclass of **android.support.v4.app.Fragment** class.

Method to create my fragment is bellow.

```
public static AddItemFragment newInstance(UUID listId, UUID itemId){

        AddItemFragment fragment=new AddItemFragment();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATA_LIST_ID,listId);
        bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATA_ITEM_ID, itemId);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
 }
```

In my onCreate method, I am attempting to read data from bundle.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mListId = (getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATA_LIST_ID) == null ? null : (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATA_LIST_ID));
    mItemId = (getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATA_ITEM_ID) == null ? null : (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATA_ITEM_ID));
}
```

Well the problem is that **getArguments()** method never returns bundle. It always returns **NULL**. I don't understand why. savedInstanceState is NULL as well.

Comment: Inside your onCreate method, try calling getIntent().getExtras()  instead of getArguments.

Comment: @svager can you show the code that how you instantiate this fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me was overriding bundle set in the Fragment with Activity's **savedInstanceState** bundle which at that point is **NULL**.

DUH...

Comment: can you explain more? I still not understand why