# bundle in fragment is null

Tags: java, android, bundle

I am trying to send data from MainActivity to SunFragment (the main fragment) as:

**MainActivity**
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

```
//  protected Location mLastLocation;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
private Location mLastLocation;

private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();//Get Fragment Manager

    //FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("loclat", 25.4358);
    bundle.putDouble("loclang",81.8463);
    Fragment SunFragment = new SunFragment();
    SunFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_pager, new SunFragment()).commit();
```

**SunFragment**

```
public class SunFragment extends Fragment {

    List<SunSession> sunsList;
    Typeface sunfont;
    Double Dlat;
    Double Dlang;

    //to be called by the MainActivity
    public SunFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    private static final String KEY_LOCATION_NAME = "location_name";
    public String TAG ="Sunfragment";
    public String location;//="No location name found";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            location = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME).toString();
            System.out.println("OnCreate location  "+location);
           // Dlat = getArguments().getDouble("loclat");
            //Dlang = getArguments().getDouble("loclang");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sun, container, false);
        onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());
        if (getArguments() != null){
            Dlat = getArguments().getDouble("loclat");
            Dlang = getArguments().getDouble("loclang");
        }
    Log.e("Lat", Double.toString(Dlat));
```

**SectionPagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2, R.string.tab_text_3};
    private final Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new SunFragment();
            //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(pos + 5);
            case 1:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);
            //return SecondFragment.newInstance();
            //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(pos + 1);
            default:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(2);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

which is giving error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.phocast.ui.main.SunFragment.onCreateView(SunFragment.java:71)
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175014/bundle-null-in-fragment) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596660/android-fragment-cant-read-bundle-bundle-is-always-null), which seems close, but unable to solve my problem.
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: why this line of code onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());

Comment: Trying to be future-safe, to save data. But deleteing that line doesnot help much

Comment: You created a brand new instance of your `SunFragment`, but where do you add that instance to the FragmentManager? Is your `SectionsPagerAdapter` creating a totally different instance of `SunFragment`?

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake: updated the mainactivity, but no change in result.

Comment: @ianhanniballake is right while you transact the fragment you create a new object of fragment HERE:- fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_pager, new SUNFRAGMENT())).commit();

Comment: @VipulChauhan: I have updated the code. Please check

Comment: I think the problem is in this line `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_pager, new SunFragment()).commit();`  use SunFragment instead of new SunFragment()

Comment: Still same error

Comment: in your Main Activity when you are replacing the fragment

Comment: @ianhanniballake: yes...I am calling the pager from SectionPagerAdapter. The code is added. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue.

Answer (score 1):

```
 mainActivity.java
 ============

  SquardFragment   
          squardFragment=SquardFragment.newInstance(matchId2,page,matchStatus);
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, squardFragment, mTag);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    if (canAddtoBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(mTag);
    transaction.commit();


  SquardFragment.java
  =================== 

   public static SquardFragment newInstance(String matchId,
        int page,String matchStatus)    {
    SquardFragment frag = new SquardFragment();
    Bundle argsBundle = new Bundle();
    argsBundle.putString("matchId", matchId);
    argsBundle.putInt("page", page);
    argsBundle.putString("matchStatus", matchStatus);
    frag.setArguments(argsBundle);
    return frag;
  }

  if (getArguments() != null) {
        matchId = getArguments().getString("matchId");
        page = getArguments().getInt("page", 0);
        matchStatus=getArguments().getString("matchStatus");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you pass a new instance of your `SunFragment` to `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace()` instead of using the instance you created with the arguments set.

```
Fragment SunFragment = new SunFragment();
SunFragment.setArguments(bundle);

//this line is the problem
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_pager, new SunFragment()).commit(); 

//change it to this
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_pager, SunFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line,

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_pager, new SunFragment()).commit();

you are giving a new object of Sunfragment each time

simply put sunFragment instead of new sunFragment.