# pass value from activity to fragment using bundle in tabbed activity

Tags: java, android, bundle

I am a java-illiterate, and still trying to develop a app for my personal use.
I have started with android-studio's "Tabbed-Activity", and mostly unaltered except a fragment and a bundle in MainActivity.

Here are my codes:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble("loclat", 25.4358);
        bundle.putDouble("loclang",81.8463);
        Fragment SunFragment = new SunFragment();
        SunFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2, R.string.tab_text_3};
    private final Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new SunFragment();
            //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(pos + 5);
            case 1:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);
            //return SecondFragment.newInstance();
            //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(pos + 1);
            default:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(2);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

And finally, The **SunFragment**, where I want my bundled data from MainActivity:

```
public class SunFragment extends Fragment {

    List<SunSession> sunsList;
    Typeface sunfont;
    Double Dlat;
    Double Dlang;

    //to be called by the MainActivity
    public SunFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    private static final String KEY_LOCATION_NAME = "location_name";
    public String TAG ="SunFragment";
    public String location;//="No location name found";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            location = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME).toString();
            System.out.println("OnCreate location  "+location);
           // Dlat = getArguments().getDouble("loclat");
            //Dlang = getArguments().getDouble("loclang");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sun, container, false);
        //onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            Dlat = getArguments().getDouble("loclat");
            Dlang = getArguments().getDouble("loclang");
        } else {
            Dlat=23.1;
            Dlang=79.9864;
        }

        Log.e("Lat", Double.toString(Dlat));
```

I have followed [this](https://mobikul.com/pass-data-activity-fragment-android/) blog to make it, but no value is passed. Kindly help.

NB. This is a better described, and detailed question of [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188813/bundle-in-fragment-is-null), which I understand, needs more code to be shown.

Comment: as you written in prev question, are you still getting error  ?

Comment: `Fragment SunFragment = new SunFragment();` and where you pass this fragment instance to your `SectionsPagerAdapter`?

Comment: Error is not there, as I have passed a value Dlat and Dlang, in my fragment itself, when getArguments() fails. Problem is getArgument() is always null

Comment: @grabarz121: I didn't get you. How should i pass the instance? The source I linked is not showing anything. Kindly explain

Comment: It's null, because an instance of `SunFragment` inside `SectionsPagerAdapter` is different then you created in`MainActivity`

Comment: can you post your setArguments method ?

Comment: @grabarz121: How to solve it?

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru: Please check MainActivity code.

Comment: What i mean is actual implementation of setArguments method. That is already static so you do not need to create object to call setArguments. So, first of all,  if no use of object delete the object creation that will save you from confusing.

Comment: @BaRud you have already solution of your problem, here `case 1: return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);`, just pass some bundles to the static method like `newInstance(Bundles bundles)` of `SunFragment` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainActivity`, your `sunFragment` is unused. Remove this part:

```
/*Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putDouble("loclat", 25.4358);
bundle.putDouble("loclang",81.8463);
Fragment SunFragment = new SunFragment();
SunFragment.setArguments(bundle);*/
```

You have to set `bundle` to `fragment` inside your `SectionsPagerAdapter`

```
case 0:
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("loclat", 25.4358);
    bundle.putDouble("loclang",81.8463);

    Fragment sunFragment = new SunFragment();
    sunFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return sunFragment;
```

But if you need to set the `bundle` to `fragment` from `MainActivity`. Then use a `callback` in that purpose.

Comment: Thanks. This is working. just one question: Is this the std way of doing this or just a work around?

Comment: Actually it depends on your requirements. In your current requirements it is ok. But in some situation it is required to set in different way.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can pass data from your mainActivity to fragment

MainActivity onCreate method

```
     adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());

     SquadsTeamListFragment  teamA =                
        SquadsTeamListFragment.newInstance(teamAData,teamBData
        adapter.addFragment(teamA, teamAName);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

use this adapter in your main activity

```
 static class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
     }
  }
```

receive data to fragment (SquadsTeamListFragment .java)

```
   public static SquadsTeamListFragment newInstance(String playerList, String   
  oppPlayerList) {
    SquadsTeamListFragment fragment = new SquadsTeamListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_TEAM_DATA, playerList);
    args.putString(ARG_OPP_TEAM_DATA, oppPlayerList);

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        playerList = getArguments().getString(ARG_TEAM_DATA);
        oppPlayerList = getArguments().getString(ARG_OPP_TEAM_DATA);

    }
}
```